# Can we add extra hidden tag in the surefire report

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

Currently generating surefire report with below details in output.xml

```
<testcase name="ExchangeHostInformation" classname="adm.exchange.PreUpgradeExchangeTest" time="0.716">
```

Is it possible to add one more extra proeprties in the same tag. My requirement is add one more tag for feature.

Can anyone give the right direction ?

Tried using custom maven plugin but not able to get existing report information

Comment: First what kind of enhancement do you need? Second the surefire report is generated by the surefire plugin (reporting plugin) which means in consequence to change the plugin for adding some other things...

Comment: Want to add one more property like @Tag info in the report. This we want to tag the funtionality of the test case and want to add in the report. Example <testcase name="ExchangeHostInformation" classname="adm.exchange.PreUpgradeExchangeTest" time="0.716" tag="Regression">

Comment: As I wrote... you have to change the plugins for that...

Comment: Any idea how to do that? Any basic guidance for this? Planned to extend "StatelessXmlReporter" and "SurefireStatelessReporter" use from Mojo class.

Comment: So you have to create your own reporter module..